# Generating a labeled image from 3D point cloud in opencv

Tags: opencv, image-segmentation, projection, point-clouds

I was trying to generate a labeled image from a a 3D point cloud. For this I had to merge 10 given frames of segmented images to a fused pointcloud. After that I applied the individual transformation matrix for each given frame and then applied the transformation matrix of the image plane on which I want to project the points. I am given with the camera intrinsics. What I have done so far is,

1. Generated a fused pointcloud by merging 10 frames.
2. After that, I am trying to project these 3D points to a given image. For this I am using the following 
   formula to convert the 3D points to 2D image coordinates:
   u = (fu * x)/z + u0 and v = (fv * y)/z + v0
3. After that I am checking whether my u and v are within the range of the image size. The size of the 
   image is 940 * 560 (940 rows and 560 columns)

   ```
   if(u >= 0 && u <= 959) && (v >= 0 && v <= 539)
   ```
4. If the condition is satisfied then I am copying the color values to this coordinate

But, I am not getting the expected result. I am sharing my code. I am not understanding what I have done wrong:

```
for (int k = 0; k < 10; k++) {
        pose_camera2world = LoadPose(GetFileName(data_dir, k) + ".transform.txt");
        RGB = cv::imread(GetFileName(data_dir, k) + ".label.png", cv::IMREAD_UNCHANGED);
        depth = cv::imread(GetFileName(data_dir, k) + ".depth.png", cv::IMREAD_UNCHANGED);
        int rows = RGB.size[0]; // 960
        int cols = RGB.size[1]; //540

        for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < rows; j++) {
                auto z = depth.at<ushort>(j, i);
                auto y = (j - intrinsics.cy) * z / intrinsics.fy;   // for cols
                auto x = (i - intrinsics.cx) * z / intrinsics.fx;   // for rows
                world_coord << x, y, z, 1;
                Eigen::Vector4f res = pose_frame_101 * (pose_camera2world * world_coord);
                point3d << res[0], res[1], res[2];
                pc.vertices.push_back(point3d);
                pc.colors.push_back(RGB.at<cv::Vec3b>(j, i));

                int u = (intrinsics.fx * res[0] / res[2])  + intrinsics.cx;
                int v = (intrinsics.fy * res[1] / res[2]) + intrinsics.cy;
                if ((u >= 0 && u <= 959) && (v >= 0 && v <= 539) && map.at<uchar>(u, v) <= res[2]) {
                    map.at<uchar>(u, v) = res[2];
                    labels_101.at<cv::Vec3b>(u, v)[0] = RGB.at<cv::Vec3b>(j, i)[0];
                    labels_101.at<cv::Vec3b>(u, v)[1] = RGB.at<cv::Vec3b>(j, i)[1];
                    labels_101.at<cv::Vec3b>(u, v)[2] = RGB.at<cv::Vec3b>(j, i)[2];
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

My output looks like this:[My output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UkPgZ.png)

Whereas it should like like this:
[The desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQccb.png)

Comment: `pose_frame_101 ` must be word to cam matrix. Is it so? Everything else looks fine

Comment: At the end `map` contains distances to your points. I suggest to fill `map` with some large number on begin and change the condition `map.at<uchar>(u, v) > res[2]`

Comment: @Gralex, thanks. I was making a mistake in this part. Now I am using the inverse. The output looks a bit better. But, I am a bit confused regarding the conversion to (u, v) from (x, y, z). Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: And, I am using the map for handling occlusions. I am thinking if objectA occludes an objectB, that means the objectA's depth is smaller than the depth of the other object at the same pixel location. That's why I am checking with < sign.

Comment: So if new point depth is smaller, then you need to override color. In you code: if new point depth larger (far away, `map.at<uchar>(u, v) <= res[2] |||| currDepth <= newDepth`), then you override color.

Comment: I have assigned very large values to map like map = 1000000 and set the condition as you said but now I get a white image.

Comment: So condition never become true? `(map.at<uchar>(u, v) > res[2]) == false` means `(100000 > res[2]) == false`?

Comment: Ok, you have `uchar` values inside =) Seams it not good type for depth

Comment: It seems so. I am getting a white image.

Comment: Try to change type for your depth map to `double` on initialization and access part

Comment: cv::Mat map(960, 540, CV_8UC1), map_106(960, 540, CV_8UC1);
map = 100000;
map_106 = 100000;

This is how I am declaring and initializing the maps.

Comment: `cv::Mat map(960, 540, CV_32FC1)` this one is float type. So access is `map<float>(u, v)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215376/discussion-between-md-siyam-sajeeb-khan-and-gralex).